# Please help me find $P(A\cap B)=?;$ $P(\overline A \cup \overline B)=?.$

Tags: probability

Today in school mathematics teacher gave us this example: $P(A)=\frac{1}{2}; $ $P(B)=\frac{5}{12}$; $P(A\cup B)=\frac{3}{4}.$ Find: $P(\overline A)=?;$ $P(\overline B)=?;$ $P(\overline {A\cup B})=?;$ $P(A\cap B)=?;$ $P(\overline A \cup \overline B)=?.$

Please help me. Thanks, for your help and your attention.

My attemp: 
$$P(\overline A)=1-P(A)=1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$ 
$$P(\overline B)=1-P(B)=1-\frac{5}{12}=\frac{7}{12};$$ 
$$P(\overline {A\cup B})=?;$$
Put $A\cup B=D,$ we have: $P(\overline {A\cup B})=P(\overline D)=1-P(D)=1-\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{4}.$

But I didn`t now how to solve the follow relation: 
$$P(A\cap B)=?$$
$$P(\overline A \cup \overline B)=?.$$

HELP ME. THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$

and

$P(\overline A \cup \overline B)=P(\overline {A \cap B})=1-P(A \cap B)$

Comment: $P(A\cap B)=P(A\cup B)-[P(A)+P(B)]=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{12}-\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{6} and $P(\overline A \cap \overline B)=1-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{5}{6},$ it is correct

Comment: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B) = \dfrac12 + \dfrac{5}{12} - \dfrac34 = \dfrac16$.

Comment: @user100991 and $P(\overline A \cup \overline B) = 1-\dfrac16 = \dfrac56$.

Comment: @user100991 Be careful with your algebra!  Start with the equation $$P[A\cup B]=P[A]+P[B]-P[A\cap B].$$ these various probabilities are just numbers, so we can use algebra to manipulate the equation.  The quantity we want to solve for is $P[A\cap B]$, so start by adding that to both sides:
$$P[A\cup B]+P[A\cap B]=P[A]+P[B].$$
Now, subtract $P[A\cup B]$ from both sides to get:
$$P[A\cap B]=P[A]+P[B]-P[A\cup B].$$

Comment: @user100991 just wondering, is my email visible in my profile?

Answer (score 0):

Union of two events: $P\left(A\cup B\right)=P\left(A\right)+P\left(B\right)-P\left(A\cap B\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Your answers for $P[\bar{A}]$, $P[\bar{B}]$ and $P[\overline{A\cup B}]$ are all fine.

For $P[A\cap B]$, we use the additivity property.  If $C$ and $D$ are disjoint, then $$P[C]+P[D]=P[C\cup D].$$

So, the fact that $P[A]+P[B]\neq P[A\cup B]$ tells us that $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint.  But we can do better than that.

It should be clear that $A\cap \bar{B}$, $\bar{A}\cap B$ and $A\cap B$ are all disjoint.  Therefore:
\begin{eqnarray}
P[A\cap \bar{B}]+P[A\cap B]&=&P[A] \\
P[\bar{A}\cap B]+P[A\cap B]&=&P[B] \\
P[A\cap \bar{B}]+P[A\cap B] + P[\bar{A}\cap B]&=&P[A\cup B]
\end{eqnarray}
(If any of these aren't completely obvious, try drawing a Venn diagram.  Do not proceed until you can see why these are true!)

Now, if you add $P[A\cap B]$ to both sides of that last equation, what happens?

Comment: You can simply little to tell, please, because you have shown very well, but I do not understand